# How to set comments to italic fonts in Neovim

Tags: configuration, neovim

I want to set my Neovim config to use an italic font for comments. I use the following code at the end of my `init.lua`:

```
local function update_hl( group, tbl )
    local old_hl = vim.api.nvim_get_hl_by_name( group, true )
    local new_hl = vim.tbl_extend( 'force', old_hl, tbl )
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl( 0, group, new_hl )
end

update_hl( 'Comment', { italic = true } )
```

When I run Neovim (v0.8.0) all comments are shown in the regular font. But if I source the `init.lua` with `:luafile %` the comments change to the desired italic font. So there seems to be no problem inside the code itself but why isn't it loaded on startup?

Comment: The highlight may be cleared when the colorscheme takes effect. The safe way to make sure your highlight settings work is to wrap it using `ColorScheme` autocmd, check for example, [this post](https://jdhao.github.io/2020/09/22/highlight_groups_cleared_in_nvim/).

Answer (score 0):

Your specific highlight is cleared by loading of colorscheme and plugins (particularly if you use TreeSitter for syntax highlighting).

Call your function to set italic font for comments after loading of colorscheme.